# Type conversion and equality behaviour

Tags: haskell, floating-point, precision

I'm new to Haskell, and just stumbled across this problem. I'm trying to figure out an explaination, but I don't have enough experience with Haskell types to be sure.

The function:

```
mystery :: Int -> Int -> Float -> Bool
mystery x y z = not ((x==y) && ((fromIntegral y) == z ))
```

behaves as it seems like it would. It's basically checking if the values are all NOT equal, but doing a type conversion from an `Integral` `y` to make sure it can be compared with `z`

If this is true, then why does:

```
case1 = do 
    if mystery 1 1 1.00000001 -- a very small number
        then putStrLn "True"
        else putStrLn "False"
```

Print False (ie. The values are all equal, so `1 == 1 == 1.00000001`) whereas:

```
case2 = do 
    if mystery 1 1 1.0000001 -- a larger number
        then putStrLn "True"
        else putStrLn "False"
```

Prints True? (ie. The values are not all equal)

I know it likely has something to do with precision, but I don't get it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might be nice if GHC would warn you of unrepresentable floating point literals, the way it does with out of range integrals. Maybe you could open a ticket on the GHC trac

Comment: You should use `Double` for all real-world code involving floating point numbers unless you have a very specific need for `Float`.

Comment: @jberryman, most fractional floating point literals cannot be represented exactly. While the suggestion has much merit, I suspect it would annoy too many people and lead to too much confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Floating point operations are generally approximate, and `==` is not one of the exceptions to that rule. Single-precision floating point (`Float`) runs out of precision pretty quickly, while the more-generally-useful double-precision floating point (`Double`) has some more. In either case, your decimal fraction will be converted approximately to binary floating point, and then the equality test will also be approximate. General rule: floating point representations are not numbers, and they are not even legitimate instances of the `Eq` class. If you want to use them, you need to pay attention to their limitations.

In this case, you need to think about when you want to consider the integer equal to the floating point representation. You may or may not want to rely directly on the built-in comparison and rounding operations.

For some of the details you'll have to think about, check out the classic [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), and don't skip the corrections and updates in the footnotes.

Comment: It's not the == that is inaccurate, it does its job perfectly.  It's the numeric literal that is too inexact as a Float.

Comment: @augustss, indeed, there is a threshold that one example crosses and the other does not. The main idea I was trying to convey is that floating point is fussy and does not always "make sense".

Answer (score 5):

Your code can be simplified to:

```
> (1.00000001 :: Float) == 1
True
```

Looks like `Float` simply doesn't have enough precision to store the last bits of `1.00000001`, so it gets truncated to plain `1`.

Answer (score 3):

`1/10^n` can't be represented in base2 floating point (IEEE 754), so the value is probably truncated.

Semantically, for integer comparison it's probably more accurate to `truncate` the floating point value.

```
mystery :: Int -> Int -> Float -> Bool
mystery x y z = not (x == y && y == truncate z)
```

Comment: While it's true that `1/10^n` can't be represented exactly, that's not really related to the problem.

Comment: The actual representation in IEEE 754 largely affects the result.  However, a representable value could also be truncated due to precision.

Comment: You can see the same problem when calling `mystery` with final arguments of `1.000000007450580596923828125` and `1.00000011920928955078125`,  which are both exactly representable in base-2 floating point. The problem here is one of precision, not representability.

Comment: Exactly, but a fractional value being larger than another fractional value doesn't imply that it needs less precision to be represented.  The mantissa may just not have enough bits.